# How to create user "nginx"?

Tags: nginx, users

Im just installed nginx from source

but when run `/etc/init.d/php_cgi start`, there is a message:
`Starting php-cgi: spawn-fcgi: can't find user name nginx`

...one more I dont know about their permission.

previously I install nginx using `yum` (CentOS)

Answer (score 20):

This will create the user and set their shell to `/bin/false` so no one can start an interactive login as this user.

```
$ useradd -s /bin/false nginx
```

Comment: can you tell me why `/bin/false`? what is `/bin/false`? my previous server also shell to `/bin/false` but I have no idea about it

Comment: `/bin/false` exists for one purpose - to provide a non-zero exit code. Contrast this with `/bin/true`, which always provides a zero exit code. The effect this has with regards to user accounts is that the user doesn't have a valid shell.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
$ sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --user-group --disabled-login --disabled-password nginx
```

Or

```
$ sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --user-group -s /sbin/nologin nginx
```

Comment: I get Option s is ambiguous (shell, system) (probably you want use shell)

Comment: I think you don't need `--disabled-password` when using `--disabled-login`. According to the documentation: `--disabled-login` - Do not run passwd to set the password.  The user won't be able to use her account until the password is set. `--disabled-password` - Like `--disabled-login`, but logins are still possible (for example using SSH RSA keys) but not using password authentication.

Comment: On arch use: `sudo useradd --system --no-create-home --user-group --shell /usr/bin/nologin nginx`

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu you can use this command:

```
adduser --system --no-create-home --shell /bin/false --group --disabled-login nginx
```